# how to include a link within the forum section itself

Tags: css

I am trying to create a forum and have the following code, which is working but just a couple of issues here...
I tried adding a `border-radius: 5px` which, from my understanding, should create a 5px border on all the corners; however my table looks weird when I tried it, and only one of the corners were affected.

Also, how would you add a link inside a forum but not using the anchor tag as seen in the image below.

```css
.categories {
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
    position: relative;
    top: 90em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.categories td {
    text-align: center;
}

.categories th {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table class="categories">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Category</th>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['category']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sub Category</th>
            <td><a href="display_music_forum_topics.php?cat=<?= htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>&admin=<?= htmlspecialchars($row['admin']); ?>&topic_id=<?= htmlspecialchars($row2['id']); ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($row2['sub_category']); ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Creator</th>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['user_uid']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['date_created']); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your table is incorrect... `tr` stands for "table row" meaning that it will create a row which has as many columns as it does children. You are using `tr` as if it were `tc` (table column)! Instead you should have one row with all the `th` (table header) and another row with the `td`s (table data).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp , http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php and please, one problem per question ;)